# FB API login popup description

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any solution to display some custom event description in FB login prompt ? I have connected a button through FB SDK API to automatically attend a user to the event. Here is the code:

```
$('.fb-event-trigger').click(function () {                  
        FB.login(function(){
          FB.api('/EVENT_ID/attending',"POST", function(response){
            console.log("rsvp: ", response);
            //$('.hidden-fb-event-link').trigger('click');
          });
        }, {
            scope: 'rsvp_event',
            return_scopes: true
});
```

And here is a login popup in which I want to put some short description before the user is automatically signed to the event:

[image]

Comment: No, there is not. Explain to the user what will happen before you trigger this whole process. Your app is not allowed to perform any such actions “automatically” anyway - it has to be actively triggered by the user, and they have to be fully aware what will happen. So your UI needs to communicate that to them in some way.

Comment: There is a button trigger but without detailed description about the event.
Thank you for your help :)